# Opposite-nearest neighbor algorithm vs. nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, path-connected

Take the traveling salesman problem, but with three slight twists:

1. You can choose a different start vertex for each of the two algorithms.
2. Each path from one vertex to another is of unique, arbitrary length (irrespective of the distances between the cities and they don't intersect).
3. Each algorithm goes to each vertex once and only once (it doesn't return to its starting vertex).
   With these conditions, is it possible for a furthest neighbor algorithm to beat a nearest neighbor algorithm.

I've tried using induction, but condition 2. really throws it off.

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222637/travelling-salesman-can-the-furthest-neighbour-algorithm-beat-the-nearest-neigh?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Travelling salesman: can the furthest-neighbour algorithm beat the nearest-neighbour?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222637/travelling-salesman-can-the-furthest-neighbour-algorithm-beat-the-nearest-neigh)

Comment: @DavidRoberts  Thanks for the link. Super helpful. The two difference between my question and that one are 1. in my question, they can start at different vertexes and 2. they don't complete a cycle, but rather just go to every vertex once (don't come back to start). How would that change my approach?

Comment: ZixunTau it was @ZacharyHunter who pointed out the question, I just voted on this Q that put in an automatic comment linking to it with formatted text :-) I can't speak to the actual mathematics, and if what you are asking is different, then that is good!

Comment: Here's what I have so far: Define FN(k) as the longest legal path from each city k. At each city, k, FN(k)>NN(k), except for their last city. In order for the FN to go a shorter distance than the NN, FN(i)<NN(j) when the FN's ending city is i and the NN's ending city is j. However, FN(i) connects two cities and NN(j) connects two cities. If NN(j) was really actually big, it would have gone to through it already via the other city. If FN(i) was small, it would have already travelled through it via the other connecting city. If they don't take those, it will make their difference even bigger.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, YES, **if the length of an edge is the same in
each direction**, then starting at a vertex $y_1$ and picking the next edge of maximum length
that visits a new vertex will return a Hamiltonian path that is **at least
as long** as the Hamiltonian path returned by starting at a vertex $u_1$ picking
the next edge of minimum length that
visits a new vertex, **for any choices of the starting vertices $y_1$ and $u_1$ in the complete graph**.
If the starting vertices are the same,
then picking the next edge of maximum length
that visits a new vertex will return a Hamiltonian path that is strictly
longer than the Hamiltonian path returned by picking
the next edge of minimum length that
visits a new vertex.

To elaborate: Let $K_N$ be a complete graph with a length
function $\ell$ on the edges of $K_N$ that satisfies the following:

1. No two edges incident to the same vertex are of the
   same length.
2. $\ell(vw)=\ell(wv)$ for every pair of vertices $w,v \in K_N$.

Let $u_1$ be a vertex in $K_N$ and let
$P^{\min}(u_1)$ be the Hamiltonian path $u_1u_2\ldots u_N$ on the
complete graph $K_N$ chosen
as follows: For each $j$, the edge $u_ju_{j+1}$ is
the edge with the *smallest* length incident to $u_j$ and not in
$\{u_ju_1, \ldots, u_ju_{j-1}\}$. Let $y_1$ be a vertex in $K_N$ and let
$P^{\max}(y_1)$ be the Hamiltonian
path $y_1y_2 \ldots y_N$ on the complete graph chosen as follows:
For each $k$, the edge $y_ky_{k+1}$ is the edge with the *biggest*
length incident to $y_k$ and not in $\{y_ky_1, \ldots, y_ky_{k-1}\}$.

> THM 1: Then there is a complete matching $M$ that matches each edge
> $u_ju_{j+1} \in P^{\min}(u_1)$ with an edge $M(u_ju_{j+1}) \doteq$
> $y_ky_{k+1} \in P^{\max}(y_1)$ that satisfies the following:
> $\ell(u_ju_{j+1}) \le \ell(M(u_ju_{j+1})) = \ell(y_ky_{k+1})$. In particular, the inequality $\ell(P^{\min}(u_1)) \le \ell(P^{\max}(y_1))$
> for any 2 vertices $u_1,y_1 \in K_N$, where, in a slight overload of notation, $\ell(W) \doteq \sum_{i=1}^{r} \ell(v_iv_{i+1})$
> for any walk $W=v_1v_2 \ldots v_rv_{r+1}$ in $K_N$.

First, for each integer $j$ let $\pi(j)$ be the integer $k$ such that
the $k$-th vertex $y_k$ of $P^{\max}(y_1)$ is the $j$-th vertex $u_j$
of $P^{\min}(u_1)$.

We construct $M$ for THM 1 as follows: We first find
$M(u_{N-1}u_{N})$, and then $M(u_{N-2}u_{N-1})$, and so on.
So let us assume that we have found $M(u_{N-j'}u_{N-j'+1})$ for
each positive integer $j'<j$. We now find $M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$

**Case 1: If there exists a *nonnegative* integer $j' < j$ such that $\pi(N-j') > \pi(N-j)$,**
put $M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$ to be the edge $y_{\pi(N-j)}y_{\pi(N-j)+1}$.
We claim the following:
$$M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1}) \doteq  
\ell(y_{\pi(N-j)}y_{\pi(N-j)+1}) \ge \ell(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1}).$$
[Indeed, let us write $N-j'\doteq a$ where $j'$ is as above, and
let us write $N-j \doteq b$. Then both $a>b$ and $\pi(a)>\pi(b)$.
Then $\pi(b)<\pi(a)$ and the construction of $P^{\max}(y_1)$ gives
$\ell(y_{\pi(b)}y_{\pi(b)+1}) \ge \ell(y_{\pi(b)}y_{\pi(a)})$
Also, $b<a$ and the construction of $P^{\min}(u_1)$ gives
$\ell(u_bu_{b+1}) \le \ell(u_bu_a)$.
But $y_{\pi(b)}=u_b$ and $y_{\pi(a)}=u_a$ so
$\ell(u_au_b)$ $=$ $\ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(b)})$.
So putting this together gives $$\ell(y_{\pi(b)}y_{\pi(b)+1}) 
\ge \ell(y_{\pi(b)}y_{\pi(a)}) = \ell(u_au_b)    
\ge \ell(u_bu_{b+1})$$
Note however that $\ell(u_bu_{b+1})=\ell(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$
[because $N-j=b$] while $\ell(y_{\pi(b)}y_{\pi(b)+1})= 
M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$ and so this gives indeed
$\ell(y_{\pi(N-j)}y_{\pi(N-j+1)})$ $\ge \ell(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$,
which is as desired.]

**Case 2: If there does not exist a $j'$ as in Case 1.**
Then the inequality $\pi(N-j) > \pi(N-j')$ for all integers
$j' < j$, so let us now set $j''$ to be the integer in
$\{0,1, \ldots , j-1\}$ so that $\pi(N-j'')$ is the
largest out of $\pi(N),\pi(N-1), \ldots \pi(N-j-1)\}$.
Then $\pi(N-j'')$ is the second largest out of
$\pi(N),\pi(N-1), \ldots \pi(N-j)$. So set
$M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$ to be the edge
$y_{\pi(N-j'')}y_{\pi(N-j'')+1}$. We claim the following:
$$M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1}) \doteq 
\ell(y_{\pi(N-j'')}y_{\pi(N-j'')+1}) \ge \ell(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1}).$$
[Indeed, let us write $N-j'' \doteq a$ and $N-j \doteq b$. Then $a>b$
while $\pi(a) < \pi(b)$.
Then $\pi(a) < \pi(b)$ and
the construction of $P^{\max}(y_1)$ implies
$\ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(a)+1}) \ge \ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(b)})$ in $K_N$.
Also $b<a$ and the construction of $P^{\min}(u_1)$
implies $\ell(u_bu_{b+1})$ $\le$ $\ell(u_bu_a)$. However,
$u_a=y_{\pi(a)}$ and $u_b=y_{\pi(b)}$ so
$\ell(u_au_b)$ $=$ $\ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(b)})$. So putting this
together gives
$$\ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(a)+1}) \ge \ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(b)}) = \ell(u_au_b)  
\ge \ell(u_bu_{b+1})$$
Note however that $\ell(u_bu_{b+1})=\ell(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$
[because $N-j=b$] while $\ell(y_{\pi(a)}y_{\pi(a)+1})=
M(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$ [because $N-j''=a$] and so this gives indeed
$\ell(y_{\pi(N-j'')}y_{\pi(N-j'')+1})$ $\ge \ell(u_{N-j}u_{N-j+1})$,
which is as desired.]

We can check that $M$ as defined above is indeed a matching as well, and
so THM 1 follows.

From this we conclude that the inequality $\ell(P^{\min}(u_1)) \le \ell(P^{\max}(y_1))$ holds
for all $u_1,y_1 \in V(K_N)$. $\surd$

We note that THM 1 holds if even if Condition 1. above for the length function $\ell$ does not hold.

---

We note that we cannot necessarily make the inequality in THM 1 strict.
To elborate, there are instances where $\ell(P^{\min}(u_1))=\ell(P^{\max}(y_1))$
for some $u_1,y_1 \in K_N$ even with Condition 1. above for the length function $\ell$ holding. Indeed, take $N=3$ and the graph $K_3$ on $\{y,w,v\}$ where $\ell(yw)=100$; $\ell(yv)=99$ and $\ell(wv)=1$. Then
$\ell(P^{\max}(y))= \ell(ywv) = \ell(P^{\min}(v))=\ell(vwy)$.

However if $u_1=y_1=v$ then [and condition 1. for $\ell$ holds] then the **strict** inequality $\ell(P^{\min}(v))< \ell(P^{\max}(v))$ holds
for all $N \ge 3$; to see this note that $M$ as constructed above
will map $u_1u_2=vu_2$
to $y_1y_2=vy_2$ and $\ell(u_1u_2) < \ell(y_1y_2)$.

---

We note that the condition that $\ell(wv)=\ell(vw)$ is a necessary
one for THM 1 to hold; otherwise take the graph $K_3$ on $\{y,w,v\}$ where
$\ell(yw)=100$; $\ell(wy)=1$; $\ell(yv)=\ell(vy)=1$ and
$\ell(wv)=\ell(vw)=2$. Then $P^{\min}(v) = vyw$ and has length $1+100=101$
whereas $P^{\max}(v)=vwy$ has length $2+1=3$.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the great response!